# insert into database only when id does not exist

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, sql-insert

I am using Postgres, In my code below I want to insert into the database only if the `id` doesn't already exist.

```
DROP TABLE json_table;
CREATE temp TABLE json_table (
    id VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY,
    str_col VARCHAR(500),
    int_col SMALLINT,
    bool_col BOOLEAN,
    json_col JSON,
    float_col DECIMAL
);
INSERT INTO json_table
    SELECT * FROM json_populate_recordset (NULL::json_table,
     '{ "insert": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "str_col": "Postgres bar data",
          "int_col": 3151,
          "bool_col": false,
          "json_col": {
            "data": "tutorials"
          },
          "float_col": 11.51099159756918
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "str_col": "Postgres tutorials data data",
          "int_col": 4237,
          "bool_col": true,
          "json_col": {
              "type": "type"
          },
          "float_col": 48.94065780742467
        }
      ]}'::json->'insert');
SELECT * FROM json_table;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `on conflict do nothing` clause. Your `id` column is the primary key of the table, so this would just work:

```
INSERT INTO json_table
SELECT * 
FROM json_populate_recordset (NULL::json_table,
     '{ "insert": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "str_col": "Postgres bar data",
          "int_col": 3151,
          "bool_col": false,
          "json_col": {
            "data": "tutorials"
          },
          "float_col": 11.51099159756918
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "str_col": "Postgres tutorials data data",
          "int_col": 4237,
          "bool_col": true,
          "json_col": {
              "type": "type"
          },
          "float_col": 48.94065780742467
        }
      ]}'::json->'insert')
ON CONFLICT (id) DO NOTHING;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ec6e21d74379fadd67d3bd4a62b446ad)**

Say this record was inserted before:

```
insert into json_table(id) values(1)
```

The above query executes without error, and inserts the second row only.

Comment: What if I had to do it on a non primary key column?

Comment: @perpetualrag: then you would need to create a `unique` constraint (or index) on that column.

Comment: Is it possible on conflict to get the id of the duplicate?

Comment: @perpetualrag: I don't know what you mean by *get `id` of the duplicate* (also note that there could be multiple conflicting `id`s).

Comment: In this example, if id = 1 was the conflict I'd like to use that id to find the conflicting row.

Answer (score 0):

Define a unique constraint on `id`:

```
alter table t add constraint unq_json_table_id unique(id);
```

You can then insert using `on conflict`:

```
insert into json_table . . .
     . . . 
     on conflict (id) do nothing;
```

Comment: is it possible on conflict to get the id of the duplicate?